# Xamarin.Android WearableRecyclerView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, wear-os

Is the WearableRecyclerView missing in Xamarin Android Wear Support Libraries 2.0.1?

I updated the Xamarin Android Wear Support Libraries nuget package to the latest version (2.0.1), but i cannot resolve the WearableRecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a broken hint path’s in the Wearable support project
Fixed in version 2.0.1.1 
https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/releases/tag/Wear-2.0.1.1